# Add onClickListener to listview item

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a list view of a thumbnail and text next to each other. **I am trying to figure out how to add a onClicklistner to each list item so when the user selects the text or thumbnails the full image will pop up.**  Below is my list object and adapter and the lazyAdapter code.

MainActivity:

```
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings, mImages);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

LazyAdapter:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
    text.setText(image_name[position]);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, image);
    return vi;
}
```

EDIT 
THis is what I ended up using.

```
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Show Full Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you want to register listener to **each** item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mStrings` and `mImages` in your `OnItemClickListener`. Assumed from your LazyAdapter that they are arrays. Maybe you can try something like this.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        String text = mStrings[position];
        YourImageClass img = mImages[position];
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowFullImageActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("TEXT", text);
        i.putExtra("IMAGE", img); // <-- Assumed you image is Parcelable
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What may help you is implementing an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`.

More info can be found here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html.

Note this is used for each row in the ListView and not the individual TextView or ImageView in each row.