# getting the text of the listitem which i clicked in android

Tags: android

i have a listview. i have to get the text of the list item which i clicked. i tried using onitemclick. but i am not able to get. can some 1 please explain me how to get it.

here is my onitemclick method

```
lstcities.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//              String str =(String) lstcities.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String S =view.getContext().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  "Click ListItem Number " +  S, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                  .show();
```

thanks
 ramu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867372/add-onclicklistener-to-listview-item - follow this

Comment: can u post the adapter class code, to see what u have tried.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.yourlayout,your list));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
           String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a `TextView`, you should be able to do

```
String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getText().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get string from ArrayList used in adapter.

like : `String str = arrayList[position]; //Assume arrayList here is String[];`

Comment: Are you use custom Adapter? Can you post all list view depended code  in your question?

Comment: yea.. i am using customadapter.

Comment: use this `View parentView = (View) view.getParent(); String textview1 = ((TextView) parentView         .findViewById(R.id.textview1)).getText().toString();`

Comment: thanks a lot awadkab it works... but i am able to get only the first list item.. how to get other list item.

Answer (score 0):

If your using customize view(own xml) for list item. You will get view of whole xml as 2nd parameter(View view) using that you can find out your textView like view.findViewById(your text view id);
If your using android define item android.R.layout.list_item_1 then typecast your view object with textview;

Using this textView you can get text of textView or like same manner any view will be accessible from list item.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is:-

```
lstcities.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{

        @Override
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
         {
            String text = (String) (((ListAdapter)parent.getAdapter).getItem(position));
            // Do what you want to with this text
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to simply add below statement :

```
String selectedFromList = (String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
```